# How can I add a dots argument (ellipsis) to an existing function?

Tags: r

Consider these functions :

```
potatoes <- function(n){
    paste(n,"potatoes!")
}

# same body, different formals
potatoes_dots <- function(n,...){
    paste(n,"potatoes!") 
}
```

What function `add_dots` can I call so that:

```
identical(add_dots(potatoes)     ,potatoes_dots) # TRUE
identical(add_dots(potatoes_dots),potatoes_dots) # TRUE
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
add_dots <- function(f) {
  a <- formals(f)
  if (!("..." %in% names(a))) formals(f) <- c(a, alist("..." = ))
  f
}

identical(add_dots(potatoes)     ,potatoes_dots)
#[1] TRUE
identical(add_dots(potatoes_dots),potatoes_dots) 
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks it does solve my issue, however `identical(add_dots(potatoes),potatoes_dots)` does not return `TRUE` on my system, because of white spaces and new lines (and because of my initial comment in the function body of `potatoes_dots`, which I removed). Obviously I don't mind, but readers trying to reproduced may be confused.

Comment: I have defined these functions exactly as shown in the question (including the comment previously there) and I get `TRUE`. Which R version are you using?

Comment: I use `R 3.3.1` on `Windows` and the opening curly brace of your modified output goes to next line, then there is 4 white spaces before paste.

Comment: I'm surprised that it worked with the comment though, it made the function not "identical".

Comment: `identical` has been changed in R 3.4.0. The documentation currently says "Note that `identical(x, y, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)` pickily tests for exact equality."